# Xbee S2C setting as a Coordinator AT mode

Tags: xbee

I am using X-CTU v6.3 in Mac OS X El Capitan with XBee S2C

In XCTU, the device is detected as

Function: ZIGBEE TH Reg

Product Family: XB24C

Firmware version: 4059

[image]

How do I configure it as a Coordinator at AT mode?

The update firmware button doesn't show anything beyond the function and product family mentioned above.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Set `CE` (coordinator enable) to `1` to configure the XBee module as a coordinator.